# how can I use Transfer Learning for LSTM?

Tags: python-3.x, conv-neural-network, lstm

I intent to implement image captioning. Would it be possible to transfer learning for LSTM? I have used pretrained VGG16(transfer learning) to Extract features as input of the LSTM.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I have discovered, we can't use Transfer learning on the LSTM weights. I think the causation is infra-structure of LSTM networks.